# Toggle through objects (as tables) using R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make my first shiny app and failing miserably. I want to be able to toggle through 3 different dataframes (and present them as tables). The idea is that I render each table (A, B, C) in the main panel by selecting them in the sidebar panel.

I am part of the way there, but struggling at the "output" stage...

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

A <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C","D"),
                      colour = c("red", "white", "blue", "orange"),
                      age =c("8", "3", "4", "5"))

B <- data.frame(ID = c("Bob", "Bill", "Jack","Dave"),
                shape = c("star", "square", "circle", "triangle"),
                age =c("15", "12", "13", "14"))

C <- data.frame(ID = c("Jane", "Jenny", "Bex","Sarah"),
                animal = c("cat", "dog", "fish", "tiger"),
                food =c("chips", "burger", "sushi", "chocolate"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Failing at my first shiny app"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("tableInput", "Table",
                  choices = c("A", "B", "C"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$results <- renderTable({
    #want to toggle through objects here
    #how do I do it?!
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be ever grateful!
Thanks!

Comment: As for any variable, you can use get : `renderTable( get( input$tableInput ))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `renderTable`, `get` the value of the object

```
get(input$tableInput)
```

i.e. `input$tableInput` returns the objects names as 'A', 'B', 'or 'C' as per the user selection.  `input` is the argument to the function and `tableInput` is the user defined name for the `Table` input choice list that store the 'A', 'B', 'C' options

`get` returns the value of the object i.e. a data.frame

-full code

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

A <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C","D"),
                colour = c("red", "white", "blue", "orange"),
                age =c("8", "3", "4", "5"))

B <- data.frame(ID = c("Bob", "Bill", "Jack","Dave"),
                shape = c("star", "square", "circle", "triangle"),
                age =c("15", "12", "13", "14"))

C <- data.frame(ID = c("Jane", "Jenny", "Bex","Sarah"),
                animal = c("cat", "dog", "fish", "tiger"),
                food =c("chips", "burger", "sushi", "chocolate"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Failing at my first shiny app"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("tableInput", "Table",
                  choices = c("A", "B", "C"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$results <- renderTable({
    get(input$tableInput)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]